# PHP SwiftMailer Not sending

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am doing some testing prior to working on some production code and need to figure out how to do an auto e-mail.

The below script runs fine and the result of the send method returns 1, as if it sends. However, nothing ever makes it to the recipient.

```
           require_once '/home/absolut2/lib/swift_required.php';

    //Create the Transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('mail.mysite.com', 25)
      ->setUsername('myuser')
      ->setPassword('password')
              ;

    /*
    You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

    //Sendmail
    $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

    //Mail
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
    */

    //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    //Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
      ->setFrom(array('rp@mysite.com' => 'RP'))
      ->setTo(array('rp@gmail.com'))
      ->setBody('Here is the message itself');


    //Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

            echo "Messages sent: " . $result;
```

Comment: Is your mail function working properly  ?

Answer (score 0):

The code itself seems fine, so I guess something else is wrong. Either check the spam queue of the recipient or maybe just the address was rejected.

[Find out if addresses were rejected](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#finding-out-rejected-addresses).

You can do that with this code:

```
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures)) {
  echo "Failures:";
  print_r($failures);
}
```